# Debian hangs when i'm inserting TLWN722N

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

I'm got a very strange problem: when i'm insert TP-LINK TL-WN722N dongle into my PC it's just hanging! If i reboot my PC with dongle plugged, it's just not booting into linux. I have tried this dongle on Win7 and everything worked normal. I'm using debian 8.

Comment: Describe "hanging", debian would be the last system capable of stopping execution of everything because of a single rogue process, even on a single processor machine.  Debian version, kernel version, and `dmesg` output (if possible).

Comment: @grochmal PC just showing static image and don't respond to any actions. Output of dmesg: http://pastebin.com/HEikUjRD
If i reboot PC when dongle plugged in i got the following: http://pasteboard.co/1TUN2FfLe.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Reload the `ath9k` driver:

```
modprobe -r ath9k && modprobe ath9k
```

Verify your wifi connection , if doesn't work use the following steps:

Install the `linux-headers` and `build-essential`

Download backport from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/) , then compile it:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
tar xvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-ath9k
make
make install
modprobe -r ath9k
modprobe ath9k
```

Comment: When i'm tried to reload driver, i got the following error: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k': Operation not permitted
(It was excecuted as root)

Comment: @Platinum_Dragon Before compiling backports?